# Making API (Network) Call From Dialog

Tags: android, networking, dialog

I'm using a dialog to make a simple API call. It's not worth making an entire Activity for, because it's just a simple EditText that is used to send a String to the server... But I'm wondering the best way to go about doing this from a UX perspective.  If the call hangs, the user may be inclined to click out of the dialog or hit the back button and dismiss the dialog. I can keep the user from doing those things, but is that a good idea? Alternatively, I can stop all calls when the dialog is dismissed so when the call returns it doesn't crash the app looking for the now null dialog.  Can somebody point me to the Android standard way of doing this, or if there isn't one suggest a good way with a detailed reason? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can start an AsyncTask and show (another)progress dialog to the user.Dismiss the progress dialog when the api has returned successfully.

Showing a progress bar/dialog will let the user know something is happening in background.You can provide the user an option to cancel the operation.

Comment: Essentially that's what I'm doing now. I'm wondering what a user would expect though if the dialog hung for a while (~10 seconds).. What would the user expect/want then?

Comment: what do u mean by dialog hung..it wont hang because you are doing stuff in background thread..